# Right arrow with background-image and repeat x (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do this arrow with CSS. It has the same background image that the left div has. Is it possible to add a background image to the triangle's border and repeat it?

[image]

Comment: Use pseudo-elements , and you can take a look here: http://css-tricks.com/triangle-with-shadow/

Answer (score 1):

My stab at this problem

**HTML**

```
<div class="left">Left Div</div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
<div class="right">Right Div</div>

.left, .right, .arrow-right {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
    background-color: #b6b6b6;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left:10px;
}

.right {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    line-height: 36px;
    margin-left: -24px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    margin-left:-4px;
    border-left: 20px solid #e4e4e4;
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vs4pzyd4/1/)